# List all recently changed files (recursive)

Tags: command-line, search, ls

So, I want to display (via `ls` for example) all files, which were changed in the last seven days. If I'm in my docroot-folder, it should be able to look "deeper".

For example:

```
File        Last changed
docroot
|- myfile1  30.11.2015
|- myfile2  10.11.2015
|- MySub
   |-sub1   30.11.2015
   |-sub2   10.11.2015
```

So, the `ls` (or whatever fits) should output `myfile1` and (if possible) 
`MySub/sub1`.

Is this doable with one command?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Of course. From the directory you are in do:

```
find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Add a redirection to it (aka `> results.txt` to store them into that file).

- `type f` does only files and not directories
- `mtime -7` does 7 days ago up to now (+7 would be 'older than 7 days')
- and it then feeds it to `ls` to show a long list

---

You can play with the `ls -l` part too:

```
find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -Rl --time-style=long-iso {} \; 
find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -R  --time-style=long-iso {} \;
```

will show a tree like method with directories in between the files in long list (1) or short list (2).

Comment: `find` has `ls` option so you could just do `find . -type f -mtime -7 -ls`

Comment: Sure but this makes it a bit more generic  (I use this method to find files I need to -remove- and can change that command to do it :) )

Comment: Also it is more appropriate to use `find ... -exec ls -l {} +` which executes `ls -l` much more efficiently - fewer times with multiple parameters. This is a standard option of `find` specified by POSIX.

Answer (score 8):

With `zsh`:

```
ls -l **/*(.m-7)
```

- `**/*` will look for files recursively starting from current directory
- `(.m-7)` is glob qualifier where `.` indicates regular file, `m-7` indicates files that were modified within last 7 days

Answer (score 3):

The following command works a dream on Mac OSX - maybe also on ubuntu …

```
find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec stat -lt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" {} \; | cut -d\  -f6- | sort -r
```

This finds files in the current directory tree which have been modified in the last 7 days, outputs the modification date + time and path, sorted newest first.

Example output:

```
2018-02-21 22:06:30 ./fmxmlsnippet.xml
2018-02-19 12:56:01 ./diff.html
2018-02-19 12:44:37 ./temp/iDDR/XMSC_fmxmlsnippet.xml
2018-02-18 22:04:05 ./temp/iDDR/XMFD_fmxmlsnippet.xml
2018-02-15 10:18:27 ./xml/iDDR/XML2_fmxmlsnippet.xml
2018-02-15 10:13:29 ./xsl/fmxmlsnippet/XML2_fmCM_AnalyseLayout.xsl
2018-02-15 10:11:36 ./xsl/.DS_Store
2018-02-15 10:10:51 ./xsl/_inc/inc.XML2_fmCM_ReportReferencesToExternalFiles.xsl
2018-02-15 10:10:09 ./xsl/_inc/.DS_Store
2018-02-15 10:07:35 ./xsl/fmxmlsnippet/XML2_fmCM_AnalyseLayout-NoAnchors.xsl
2018-02-15 10:07:35 ./xsl/_inc/inc.XML2_fmCM_AnalyseLayout.xsl
```

I'd be grateful of any feedback from ubuntu users.

Comment: The only solution that worked well for me on Mac. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome @artnikpro!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what was asked for... but much easier to remember...

```
ls -alRt docroot
```

or

```
ls -alRt /path/to/top/level/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```bash
find root.d -type f -newermt "-7 days"
```

**or**

```bash
find root.d -type f -newermt "$(date -d "$(date)-7days")"
```

Tested with **bash** using:

| Ubuntu | Find |
| --- | --- |
| 23.04 | 4.9.0 |
| 22.04 | 4.8.0 |
| 20.04 | 4.7.0 |

*also verified in macOS(darwin) zsh and bash*

*use the following to find out which versions you have*

```bash
cat /etc/lsb-release
find --version
```

Assume the following directory structure and files with these relative modified timestamps

```
root.d/
├── file_c (-5 years)
└── level_1.d/
    ├── file_a (-45 minutes)
    └── file_b (-1 second)
```

### example 1

find all the files recursively in **root.d** with a modifed date *"newer than"* 10 minutes ago

```bash
NEWER_THAN="-10 minutes"
find root.d -type f -newermt "$NEWER_THAN"
```

result

```
root.d/
└── level_1.d
    └── file_a
```

### example 2

find all the files recursively in **root.d** with a modifed date *"newer than"* 10 hours ago and older than (*"not newer than"*) 10 minutes ago

```bash
NEWER_THAN="-10 hours"
OLDER_THAN="-10 minutes"
find root.d -type f -newermt "$NEWER_THAN" -not -newermt "$OLDER_THAN"
```

result

```
root.d/
└── level_1.d
    └── file_b
```

### example 3

find all the files recursively in **root.d** with a modifed date older than (*"not newer than"*) 10 days ago

```bash
OLDER_THAN="-10 days"
find root.d -type f -not -newermt "$OLDER_THAN"
```

result

```
root.d/
└── file_c
```

## considerations

after a few simple tests, I am confident the comparisons are strictly greater/less not equal.
[relevant discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169798/what-does-newermt-mean-in-find-command)
[another simlar discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238738/find-files-newer-than-15-seconds-but-older-than-2-seconds)

```
-newerXY reference
      Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being considered is
      newer than timestamp Y of the file reference.  The letters
      X and Y can be any of the following letters:

      a   The access time of the file reference
      B   The birth time of the file reference
      c   The inode status change time of reference
      m   The modification time of the file reference
      t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
```

[find man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

7 days that's 60 seconds*60minutes*24hours*7days
 = 604800 seconds

Find out current date in seconds (Unix epoch time):

```
$ date +%s
1448876323
```

Subtract the 7 days in seconds:

```
expr $(date +%s) - 604800
1448271548
```

Now take `stat` command and print stats for all files in format "name + time in seconds" and use `awk` to crop off those files whose modification time is greater that that date we calculated

```
$ stat --printf="%n %Y\n" $HOME/* | awk '$2 > 1448271265 {print $0}'
/home/xieerqi/1448428697574.png 1448429613
/home/xieerqi/1448763343273.png 1448763478
/home/xieerqi/1510DRIVE 1448352453
/home/xieerqi/addRemoveDistribution 1448666843
/home/xieerqi/add-update.awk 1448716356
/home/xieerqi/add-update.sh 1448625092
```

Particularly of interest are last 3 files, because I know I was working them on less that 7 days ago. Thus I know it works

Comment: Note that instead of `awk '$2 > 1448271265 {print $0}'` you can diretly say `awk '$2 > 1448271265'`. On a true condition, awk prints the current line as a default action.